# How to copy struct attributes and change the copy but not the original

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose this structure

```
typedef struct solution {
    int *vector;
    float cost;   
}solution;
```

How can I pass this to a function to operate in a copy and not in the original? Example:

```
solution change(solution c){
    solution d;
    d.vector = c.vector;
    d.vector[1]++;
    return d;
}

int main(){
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    solution c;
    c->vector = a;
    solution d = change(c);

    printf("%d %d\n",c.vector[1],d.vector[1]);
}
```

I wanted that to print `3 2`.

I'm sorry to ask such an elementary question, but from what I searched in similar problems, it was recommended `memcpy`, but it does the same from the above code.

Comment: *How* did you use `memcpy`?

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++` ? The answer (c/w)ould differ even when ignoring `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is basically that you are using raw pointers: don't.  Use `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <vector>

struct solution { // No need for typedef - C++ does that automatically.
    std::vector<int> vec;
    float cost = 0.0f;     // Always good to initialize
};

solution change(const solution& c) { // By default, pass 'big' objects by const reference 
    solution d;
    d.vec = c.vec; // This will allocate a new vector and copy the value.
    d.vec[1]++;
    return d;
}

int main(){
    const int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    solution c;
    std::copy( std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(c.vec));
    const solution d = change(c);

    printf("%d %d\n",c.vec[1],d.vec[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`solution c` and `solution d` both hold a pointer pointing to the same memory location, the address of int a[3]. I think what you dont understand is `d.vector = c.vector`, its not actually copying the array just the pointer to it so c and d are actually pointing to the same array so when you try to print it you get the same value. You probably want to look at `malloc`(or `new` if you are using c++) and try to get a better understanding of pointers.